# How can I remove a row from UITableView immeidately after adding it?

Tags: xcode, templates, core-data

I've added to my `UITableView` the following method to provide the user with the option to delete a line:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I have copied this method from the XCode template with the option

> Use CoreData for Storage

Once the user pushes the `addButton` in the `UITableView` a new `UIView` is opened where he should enter the information for a new entity.

Then the user touches the `saveButton` in the `UIView`. The information is read and stored in the context. The `UIView` is closed and the user will get back to `UITableView`.

The new entry now appears in a new row. If the user now realizes he has made ​​a mistake and wants to delete this row immediately (wipe from left to right and then touch "Delete") the row remains and nothing else happens. The following error is thrown to me:

```
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. 
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. 
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1)
must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), 
plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted). 
with userInfo (null)
```

But deleting the row works if I exit the app before the deleting happens. (and re-viewed, and then delete)

In `controllerDidChangecontent` only `[self.tableView endUpdate]` is called.

My method looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        //NSLog(@"DATE: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);


        for (UILocalNotification *notification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {

            NSLog(@"N: %@", notification.fireDate);
            NSLog(@"O: %@", [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"zeit"]);

            if (notification.fireDate == [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"zeit"]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
                NSLog(@"GELÖSCHT!");
            }
        }

        // Save the context.
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            /*
            Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

            abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }   
}
```

I think the row was added but not commited. And then it will attempt to delete a row that it does not know about. Do I understand this correctly?
But I do not know exactly where to fix the error.
What can I do? Does anybody know?

Comment: I think you have to add some more words to tell us what you mean. I do not understand some of it.

Comment: A picture is always helpful. Perhaps then It would be more clear. :)

Comment: You understand the the error that I post?
How I do clear teh problem... What you want to know?

Comment: I reformatted your qw (right or wrong well well). So. I only see my rewriting of your sentances (since no moderator has looked at it).

Comment: Things I did not understand was 1. (after codeframe. An exception was...). But the deletion work if I exit the app before the deleting happens, (and re-viewed, and then delete). 2. (after codeframe. if (editingStyle ==...)) I think he added the Row but not implemented it. And then he will delete a row that he does not know. // He? Is he perhaps a function or a class.

Comment: 1. I mean: When I add an Entity and close the App and restart the App, then I can delete the Row without problems.
2. I mean: The UITableView add the row but the UITableView (or what else) does not know, that there is a new row... He is the UITableView...

Comment: Perhaps you should write this in your qw. (Don't know. edited a lot of qw's lately, people does things differently. The funniest qw I edited today was one that started with. "Please write this code for me that will achieve this". Hilarious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message: you **also have to delete the row from the table view**.

If you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, you can do it like this:

```
// in controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:
case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
break;
```

Also notice that your `fetchedResultsController` has to be informed that it should re-fetch the a new result set - otherwise `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` will return the old value. So you need to insert:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
```

It will recreate itself lazily with the correct sections and rows.

Comment: Yes thats okay. But the XCode Template includes this method.
In my code there is also these method that you mean...
I think the error comes from the controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller. Am I correct there?

Comment: The call in `controllerDidChangeContent:` is correct. That just shows up in the error message because that is where the final check occurs. What does your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` say?

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

Comment: Okay that I understand. But where should I put the self.fetchedResultsController = nil? Eachtime where a Entity is delte?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you change the data you have to reset the fechedResultsController.

Comment: Okay thats sounds good :) But with <pre><code>self.fetchedResultsController = nil;</code></pre> the fetchedResultController is not reset... Only to nil... How can I reset the fetchedResultController? How can I reload the Controller?

Comment: The fetched results controller should create itself. You should have a method `(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` (a getter) that returns the FRC or creates a new one with your parameters if it `nil`. Follow this very common pattern from Apple's sample projects.

Comment: Yes that I have :) So what I have to do is, after the context has save, self.fetchedResultsController = nil; and the call the getter with: self.fetchedResultsController = [self fetchedResultsController]... I that right? I understand that now right?

Comment: No - next time you use self.fetchedResultsController it will create itself.

Comment: Sorry but what you mean with "next time you use self.fetchedResultsController it will create itself"? I dont know what you mean with that... Sorry for the stupidness, but I'm a little confused with that...

Comment: Read my comment "The fetched results controller should create itself..."

Comment: I'm now so far, that the deletion does work. But now, when I delete the first row I get this exception: "controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  Attempt to delete more rows than exist in section." Damn, I'm get CRAZY! EDIT: What I have found is, that when I push the Delte Button, the Method didChangeObject is call 2 times... I checked it with a simple NSLog(@"Test")... The Console spend 2 times "Test" when I push the Delete Button...

Comment: So I guess you are close to having this issue resolved. Please consider checking the tick mark on my answer.

Comment: Done :) But what about the new problem? Now, when I delete the first row I get this exception: "controllerDidChangeContent:. Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. Attempt to delete more rows than exist in section." What I have found is, that when I push the Delte Button, the Method didChangeObject is call 2 times... I checked it with a simple NSLog(@"Test")... The Console spend 2 times "Test" when I push the Delete Button...